# Remove open sans font link from wordpress head

Tags: wordpress

How do I go about removing the open sans font link from Wordpress's header without using a plugin?

I'm currently using twentyfifteen theme and I was using Disable Google Fonts plugin but I'm trying to cut down on plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `dequeue_style` with an additional priority call:

```
function wpso_dequeue_google_fonts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'twentyfifteen-fonts' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpso_dequeue_google_fonts', 20 );
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style

Use this function in a child theme, because if you edit the original twentyfifteen theme, your changes will get overwritten with one of WP's peridodic theme updates. See [Child Themes « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

And then remove any calls for Open Sans from `font-family:` rule in the stylesheet.

Comment: I added that code into my functions file in twenty fifteen but it didn't work the link is still in the head when I go to view source?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php file of your child theme.

```
function remove_open_sans() {
   wp_dequeue_style( 'twentyfifteen-fonts' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','remove_open_sans');
```

The Google fonts are being added like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfifteen-fonts', twentyfifteen_fonts_url(), array(), null );
```

So you need to dequeue the styles like they are added.

Comment: I added that into the top of my functions file but the link is still in the head. Any ideas?

Comment: Can this code only be used in a child theme of twentyfifteen?

Comment: @JonnyJordan It's encouraged to do so. Because if you overwrite the twentyfifteen theme and update it, you will lose all your adjustments.